# Specific price per quantity

Tags: price, quantity, option, select

I'm trying to set a product with different prices depending on quantity "chosen from drop-down"

But I have no idea how to create this. basically I have a product which comes in this quantities: 20, 32, 42, 56, 65, 75, 88 ,106, 126, 138 so user should select one of this options to have corresponding price, I cannot use the increment option as the quantity is not multiple.

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-units-and-quantities.html

Comment: did you have any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can add price based on qty using "Tier price" for product.

For adding tier price you need to open product->price tab and there is field call tier price.

Comment: yes, i have the tier price already, but what i want is the user in frontend to chose the specified quantity from a dropdown box, so they dont enter a number of product i dont want...

Comment: you can do once thing:
$qtyStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();

Based on qty you can create dropdown.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but no, as i have other products which dont use the same option

Comment: If other product has other attribute set than you can add attribute set wise condition.

Comment: im sorry, but i dont get what you are saying, no offense

Answer (score 0):

If the quantities you listed above are fixed, you can try adding following code to `catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml` file.

```
<label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
<?php if ($_product->getSomeValue()): ?>
    <select id="qty" name="qty">
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="32">32</option>
        <option value="32">45</option>
    </select>
<?php else: ?>
    <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
<?php endif ?>
```

**Note**: `$_product->getSomeValue()` is just a dummy check, I'm assuming you have some way to distinguish regular qty from drop down qty products.

Would something like this work for you?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what for you mean by dummy check? For the quantities i could use a tier price, also i need to be sure that this code should apply only for a specific category as other products won't use this.